# Can Mage Hand extinguish exposed flame light sources?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light, cantrips

I want the ability to extinguish exposed flame light sources for my character and I was wondering if Mage Hand would be sufficient for the task.

Staying within the scope of the actions a Mage Hand is allowed to take, would it be able to extinguish exposed flame light sources such as candles, torches and campfires?

Comment: This sounds more like something [Prestidigitation](http://engl393-dnd5th.wikia.com/wiki/Prestidigitation) is for. *You light or snuff out a small fire*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*[Mage Hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand)* allows you to

> manipulate an object, open an unlocked door or container, stow or retrieve an item from an open container, or pour the contents out of a vial.

As an example for *interacting with objects around you* the rules provide some examples, which include

> extinguish a small flame

*Mage Hand* is not explicitly referencing the *use an object* action, but I think these are some appropriate guidelines.

I would argue, that a campfire would not count as **small** fire and may require multiple actions.

*This is heavily DM fiat, but I for myself allow anything which does not require a skill check by itself.*

Comment: If the flame is small enough to be extinguished by the contents of a small vial it would be within the rules of the text.

Comment: When I asked the question what I had in mind was the specific ways it would be allowed to do so but the answer seems to be that a Mage Hand can do anything a regular hand can, other than a few specifically forbidden actions. That's a good enough answer for me.

Comment: Pour out a vial of water  on a candle or torch, or cover the flame with something, like a 9lb bucket of sand... or just pick up the candle or torch and grind it out on the ground.

Answer (score 8):

[image: candle snuffer]

A candle snuffer was typically used to extinguish candles, lanterns, and other small flames. It is well within the capabilities of Mage Hand provided that the action is within the range requirements, so it could carry one of these over to snuff out such a flame.

Mage Hand (paraphrased):

> You can carry an object up to 10 lb. As an action you can move the hand a distance of 30 ft. each time you cast it, provided it stays within 30 ft of you.

A similar item on a larger scale could be used on torches and stay within the 10 lb limit.

A gallon of water weighs about 8 lb., so putting out a campfire is pushing the limits of Mage Hand. Although it could separate the logs, it may take more than one casting to carry enough water to put out a fire.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but where is that misspelled quote from? It is not in the 5th edition text of Mage Hand.  Note that in the 5th edition the weight limit is 10 pounds and the range is 30 feet.

Comment: The relevant part of the description for [Mage Hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand): "The hand vanishes if it is ever more than 30 feet away from you or if you cast this spell again.

You can use your action to control the hand. You can use the hand to manipulate an object, open an unlocked door or container, stow or retrieve an item from an open container, or pour the contents out of a vial. You can move the hand up to 30 feet each time you use it.

The hand can't attack, activate magic items, or carry more than 10 pounds."

Comment: I quoted it mostly because you paraphrased it instead. I mostly just included it in my comment as a reference.

Comment: @V2Blast - yes I paraphrased mainly because I am presenting a method for snuffing small flames not explaining Mage Hand. But thank you for the comment.

Comment: That is important to point because the most common use of quotation blocks here is to, well, quote from some text.

Comment: @YannickMG -- even though it is not word for word, it is still a quote. You just have to be careful not to change the meaning when paraphrasing. it would be an exact quote if I added ellipsis and brackets.